# Is this "How do I make this short one-liner even shorter"-esque question constructive?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I saw this question on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17961200/fastest-way-to-add-numeric-array-to-itself-and-print-one-liner

The OP already has a very short one-liner, and asks whether there is an even shorter way to write it. The one-liner works, and is already so short that it's borderline readable (due to omitted whitespace). I don't deny that there might be a possible answer which can be educational, but the question itself has very very little practicality.

Note that this is not about "shorten my code" questions in general; I am asking about this *specific* question.

Comment: It's closed now.

Comment: Isn't http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ for that sort of question?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc, yes. But I'm wondering if it's on topic on SO, even if just marginally.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc no, it isn't. [codegolf.se] is for questions that are _fun_ and _challenging_ to solve or golf. Language-agnostic questions are the most typical ones there. This isn't fun to solve or language-agnostic. It might be reworded to fit the scope, but it won't be a good question there. For one, the asker shouldn't reveal his solution right away if there's a decent chance no shorter solution exists. It takes the fun away.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Gilbert, daxim, and whoever else expressed the sentiments that this question belongs on [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/). As a non-member, I'm far from an expert on the community or what the site allows, but it appears to be within their list of [allowed topics](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Then again, we all know that "your question would be a *better* fit on another site" is not a sufficient reason to close a question. If the question is on-topic for Stack Overflow, it should be allowed to stay.

But I don't think this one is. Aside from the fact that we've basically reached a consensus (spurred mostly by the genesis of a dedicated site for it) that code golf questions are off-topic for Stack Overflow, there are several specific problems with this question that jump out at me:

1. It asks for "a fast, ugly, golfish, oneline way" to do something. That's not what we do on SO.
2. There are no clear and objective standards given by which the answers should be judged. That leads to a situation where there are multiple correct answers. Or worse, *no* correct answers.
3. It doesn't solve a practical, real-world programming problem. No one in the real world writes obfuscated, ugly, one-line code. They write *working* code that is *sufficiently* fast (using objective criteria like benchmarks), clear, and easy to maintain.
4. It doesn't show any real research effort.
5. Subjectively, it doesn't tend to attract detailed, high-quality answers. The accepted answer is a good example of this problem, but I hardly think it is an isolated case.

Some of those issues may *also* make this question problematic on Code Golf. It should not be migrated there directly. If the asker wishes to read their guidelines and modify his question to comply with them, I would encourage him to re-ask.

Comment: To be fair, I'm aware that OP did try CodeGolf (see his [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17961200/fastest-way-to-add-numeric-array-to-itself-and-print-one-liner#comment26252667_17961200)), but the community there rejected his question.

Comment: @old Huh, didn't see that. Weird. They said this isn't enough of a challenge for them? Oh well, I'm not a good person to discuss that. I don't see the point in code golf altogether...